# Managing project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've got a couple of java projects that depend on the same piece of code. Lets call them:

```
Project A
Project B
ComponentX.java
```

The projects are set up like this:

```
Project A > ComponentX.java
Project B > ComponentX.JAR
```

This set up where Project B contains ComponentX's jar file is inconvenient. Any time I make a change to ComponentX.java, I need to remember to export the Jar to Project B. It also makes debugging Project B difficult. There has to be a better way, I just don't know what to google. I'm using Eclipse. I use Maven so any solution using that would be Ok, although I'm hoping that there is a simple Eclipse based solution.

I'm guessing I'll need to move componentX into its own project and somehow make the other two depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a lightbulb moment. Any maven project can be imported into any other maven project the exact same way you'd import any other dependency. Seems obvious now but I've only ever imported libraries other people wrote.

So if you've got three projects:

- WebApp
- DesktopApp
- Dependency

Where both WebApp and Desktop need to reference Dependency. This could also apply in a case where there is repeated code in two projects, just pull that out into it's own project and remove it from both.

Simply make Dependency project a Maven project by right clicking > Configure > Convert to Maven Project. You'll get a .pom file with something like this at the top:

```
<groupId>Dependency</groupId>
<artifactId>Dependency</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Then all you have to do is add that as a dependency to any other project's .pom that needs access to it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>Dependency</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dependency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

That's it

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want to create a new library project that will be used by both Project A and Project B as a standard Maven `<dependency>`.

There are few guides available online. If your projects are all part of the same multi-module Maven build you can take a look at [Creating a Multi Module Project guide on spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#initial).

Comment: I wrote my own answer since the spring guide had a lot more information than I needed for this. Thanks for the input though it did help me out